# Don't need google sign in to do android endpoint auth?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

So i was playing with the google sign in and endpoint auth. Got everything figured out and can do the auth just find using

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context, "server:client_id:fakewhateverstring.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    credential.setSelectedAccountName("whatever@gmail.com");
```

The thing I noticed is that I don't need google sign in at all. I tried commenting out all the google sign in code and put in whatever my email was for account i use on emulator. And it worked. Seems very insecure to me. Is there a better way to do it that requires google sign in and just not some email address that is already on the phone account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works is this: when a user logs in with a google account in the client, the `User` object in the API method will be injected into the API method on the backend. It is then your responsibility to check if that `User` object is null or not and throw an unauthorized exception.

From my testing I have found that if a user is already logged in with their Google account on an Android device, and you set the Email the way you did to that specific email, the backend will indeed inject that `User` object - after all, the client IS signed in.

However, if you just pass in a non-logged in email, the User object won't be injected.

Play around with this and you will get a feel for it and see how it is actually indeed secure.